# How to create custom shapes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create this shape using canvas
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3dhT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `Shape` interface, and implement `createOutline` method. `Outline.Generic` accepts any `Path` object, so you can build any shape by adding lines, curves, rounded rects, etc.

```kotlin
class CustomShape(val param: Int): Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ) = Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
        // build your path here depending on params and size
    })
}
```

If the shape has no parameters, it can be defined as `object` instead of `class`.

Then you can pass this custom shape in any modifier which accepts `Shape`, like `Modifier.background(color, shape = CustomShape(...))`, `border`, or in views like `Surface`.